# How to vertically center a button in a container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

How do I vertically center my view button within the box container.

I tried styling the button with `vertical-align:center;` but it didn't work.

I tried adding:   `position: relative; top: 50%; transform: perspective(1px) translateY(-50%);`.

But this just makes half of the button appear on top of the container and the other half inside the container

View:

```
<div class="container signup2">
<div class="title container">
  <h2> Enrolled Courses: </h2>
</div>
<div class="container box">
  <div class="row col-centered">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 index">
      <h3><%= course.name %></h3>
      <p><%= course.description %></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <%= link_to "View", course_path(course), class: "btn button buttonmargin align" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

custom.scss:

```
.signup2 {
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.title {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.index {
  text-align: left;
}

.align {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: perspective(1px) translateY(-50%);
}

.button {
  background-color: #20B2AA;
  color: white;
}

.buttonmargin {
  margin-left: 150px;
}
```

[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYBqZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try using flex.

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 align"> //moved align class here
      <%= link_to "View", course_path(course), class: "btn button buttonmargin" %>
    </div>
```

And css for **align** :

```
.align {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Here is codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-field-1wwn7)

Comment: @subham Verma I tried that but now my button is fixed to the top of the container like it was before I change align to translateY(-50%).

Comment: I don't understand yet. Can you make this code sandbox or any screenshot for reference?

Comment: What I meant to say was that the View button is fixed to the top of the container after I added the css you sent me for align. Before I added it, half of the button was above the container and the other half was inside it.

Comment: I edited the post to add an image of what it looks like now after I used your suggestion

Comment: I coundn't see it on my code. Can you please update this and share link here??https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-field-1wwn7

Comment: @newbierailsdeveloper I have updated my code . It seems like you are missing something. Check here(https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-field-1wwn7)

Comment: @subham Verma. Thats exactly what I added to my code. I didn't miss anything. This is how it looks like now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYBqZ.png

Comment: the button is stuck to the top of the container instead of being in the middle

Answer (score 0):

Shubham's answer is almost correct. However, the css class that needs to have a `display:flex` property is actually on the row itself. Instead of modifying the CSS, Bootstrap 4.0 has a built-in class called `.d-flex` that you can pair with `.align-items-center` and it will work. See examples below:

With no defined height properties:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="col-12">
            Anything in here will be vertically centered
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With a defined height property on the container:

```
<div class="container d-flex align-items-center" style="height:500px">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            Anything in here will be vertically centered
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried doing that but the button is fixed to the top of the container instead of being in the middle

Comment: From the sound of things, you have a defined height added to one of your classes. If there is a height property, lets say on the container class, you must put the d-flex and align-items-center on that (see my edited code).